# How can I sync the documents of shareJS with a fileSystem

Tags: node.js, git, express, operational-transform

I am trying to create a simple text editor that has Operational Transform  multi tenant support and while it was reasonably easy to get the editor working and syncing across clients using shareJS, my problem is I would like to sync the shareJS **doc**'s with a Folder structure on the Server side (this will eventually be a git repo)

I am completely new to [sharejs](http://sharejs.org/) and Operational Transforms and found the shareJS documentation a little tough to follow for more complex example.

Any suggestions on How might I approach this problem?

What I have tried to do is to implement a client on the server side that could get the entire doc text on update but (and this is the lack of experience I'm sure) the only way I can think to accomplice is to use the client api to cycle through all documents and write each to a file. But to me this sounds horribly inefficient. Can anyone point me to any resources that might help or offer some advice as to how I could approach this?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit late thought but you can still call getSnapshop method on the server side and dump that into a file on your file system. If it is not run locally you can create a tiny router with express on your local machine that listen for post request and you post the dumped file into the post request body on your sharejs server and then on your machine dump the post request body to a file, that should work.

Beware of security considerations if you use a auth system on your server.